# Python check for other rows while iterating through for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tuples

So I have this list of tuples as shown below:

```
[(21, 2, 10.0),
(21, 104, 20.0),
(22, 1, 371.0),
(22, 104, 742.0),
(23, 1, 114.0),
(23, 104, 228.0),
(25, 1, 2.0),
(25, 104, 2.0)]
```

The context of each number, in order, is an id, sku_id and quantity. The goal is to go through each batch of tuples with the same ID and do the following:

- Check that any entry with a sku_id of 104 has another entry within the same quote_id
- That other entry must be half the quantity as the previous row.

In the example above, the rows with the id of 25 would match as the row with sku_id being 1 does not have half the quantity as the row with sku_id 104. This should be appended to a final set.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: look at  https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Comment: There are so many edge cases here. What if the ids are not sorted (in the case they arent then itertools.groupby wont work), What if there isn't another id? Do you insert one? throw an error? What if the quantity is not half? Do you want it changed? Do you want to get a list of the ones that don't follow the criteria?

Comment: Is your data pre-sorted so that id pairs are always consecutive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `collections.defaultdict` to make a dictionary of the orders:

```
all_orders = defaultdict(dict)
for i, sku, qty in data:
    all_orders[i][sku] = qty
```

`all_orders` is now:

```
{
    21: {2: 10.0, 104: 20.0},
    22: {1: 371.0, 104: 742.0},
    23: {1: 114.0, 104: 228.0},
    25: {1: 2.0, 104: 2.0}
}
```

Then just loop through that and find if they meet the criteria

```
for i, orders in all_orders.items():
    if 104 not in orders:
        continue
    if len(orders) == 1:
        print("Needs to be more than one order if sku is 104")
        continue
    half_104_qty = orders[104] / 2
    for qty in orders.values():
        if qty < half_104_qty:
            continue
    else:
        print("There must be another order half the quantity of the order with sku 104")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code using dictionaries:

```
lis = [(21, 2, 10.0),
(21, 104, 20.0),
(22, 1, 371.0),
(22, 104, 742.0),
(23, 1, 114.0),
(23, 104, 228.0),
(25, 1, 2.0),
(25, 104, 2.0)]
print(lis)
out = {}
for i in lis:
    temp = out.get(i[0],False)
    if temp:
        if i[1]==104 and i[2]==temp*2:
            pass
        else:
            print(i[0])
    else:
        out[i[0]] = i[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
data = [(21, 2, 10.0),
        (21, 104, 20.0),
        (22, 1, 371.0),
        (22, 104, 742.0),
        (23, 1, 114.0),
        (23, 104, 228.0),
        (25, 1, 2.0),
        (25, 104, 2.0)]

data_map = {}

for item in data:
    id  = item[0]
 
    if id not in data_map:
        data_map[id] = [item]
    else:
        data_map[id].append(item)


for key, value in data_map.items():
    for index, item in enumerate(value ,1):
        id = item[0]
        if index != len(value):
            for next_item in value[index:]:
                if item[2] * 2 != next_item[2]:
                    print(f"{item} does not match {next_item}")
```

**Output:**

[image]